# How to use animateToRegion function in react native maps?

Tags: react-native

I am using MapView of react-native map clustering and Marker and callout of react-native-maps. I am unable to use `animateToRegion`.
It shows me `this.mapView.animateToRegion is not a function`

```
 <MapView
 ref={map=>{mapView = map}}
 provider='google'
 clustering={true}
 onClusterPress={this.onPressCluster}
 region={this.state.region}
 onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
 onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
 style={styles.map}
 showsUserLocation={true}
 followUserLocation={true}
 zoomEnabled={true}
 ScrollEnabled={true}
 showsBuildings={true}
 showsMyLocationButton={false}/>
```

Answer (score 9):

```js
animate(){
    let r = {
        latitude: 42.5,
        longitude: 15.2,
        latitudeDelta: 7.5,
        longitudeDelta: 7.5,
    };
    this.mapView.root.animateToRegion(r, 2000);
}

render(){
    return(
        <MapView
            ref = {(ref)=>this.mapView=ref}
            region={{
                latitude: 35.688442,
                longitude: 51.403753,
                latitudeDelta: 0.5,
                longitudeDelta: 0.5,
            }}
            onPress={()=>this.animate()}
        >

           ...markers...

        </MapView>
    );
}
```

Comment: When I try this approach `mapView.root` returns null, would you mind telling me which version of React Native Maps you're using?

Comment: Just use `this.mapView.animateToRegion(r, 2000);`

Comment: can you tell how to do this using functional component and useRef

Comment: @yaswanthkoneri . I am too, getting the same issue with useRef in react-native-map. when i am doing ref={ref => mapRef = ref} then i get null in mapRef and if i do   ref={mapRef} in this case i  am not able to get "animateToCoordinate" function. Please help me if you found any solution for this issue else i ll have to create a class component.

Answer (score 1):

```js
clickOnSearchedAddress = (placeId, index, dscrpt) => {
  getLatLongFromAddress(placeId).then((response) => {

    let r = {
      [Constants.KEY_LATITUDE]: response.geometry.location.lat,
      [Constants.KEY_LONGITUDE]: response.geometry.location.lng,
      latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta,
      longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta
    }
    this.mapView.animateToRegion(r, 1000)
    Keyboard.dismiss()
    isSetTextProgramatically = true;
    this.setState({
      search: dscrpt,
      searchData: [],

    })

  }).then((error) => { })
}


<MapView

  ref={ref => this.mapView = ref}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  style={[styles.map, , { width: this.state.width }]}

  initialRegion={region}
  onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
  showsMyLocationButton={true}
  showsCompass={true}
  showsUserLocation={true}
  onMapReady={() => this.setState({ width: width - 1 })}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the prop is not called ref, but instead mapRef. Pass the ref in there, and it should work.

You would then also have to call it with something like this `this.mapView.[current/map]animateToRegion`. Just check the mapView object you get.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You can use animateCamera instead of animateRegion:

- Class component:

```js
    <MapView ref={(ref) => this.mapViewRef = ref} />
```

- Functional component:

```js
    const mapViewRef = React.useRef(null);

    ...

    <MapView ref={mapViewRef} />
```

Then, using ref to call `animateCamera()`:

- Class component:

```js
    // example region:
    const camera =  {
        center: {
            latitude: 10.775382995605469,
            longitude: 106.68632109704656,
            latitudeDelta: 0.002305,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0010525,
        }
    };
    this.mapViewRef.animateCamera(camera, {duration?: number});
```

- Functional component:

```js
    mapViewRef.current?.animateCamera(camera, {duration?: number});
```